# Artin's Algebra 2nd ed. chapter 1 exercise 1.5

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

> Let $A,B$ and $C$ be matrices of size $l\times m$, $m\times n$, and $n\times p$. How many multiplications are required to compute the product $AB$? In which order should the triple product $ABC$ be computed, so to minimize the number of multiplications required?

I think to compute $AB$ we'll need $m\times (l\times n)$ multiplications: it requires $m$ steps to compute each entry and there are $n\times p$ entries.

And for $BC$ we need $n\times (m\times p)$ multiplications.

So, for $(AB)C$ we need $mln+nlp$ multiplications;

and for $A(BC)$ we need $nmp+mlp$ multiplications (where I think here we just add up the number of steps it costs for each matrix multiplication).

---

May I ask, if I'm on the right track, how can we go further on the conclusions of which computation has the minimum steps?

Comment: Yes, you are right.  Which one is smaller depends on the values of $l,m,n,p$.

Comment: @saulspatz Thank you for you reply :) I was wondering if we could draw further conclusions on $mln+nlp$ and $nmp+mlp$ (maybe by cases) to make the answer look more organized. Perhaps not?

Comment: I don't think so.  With $N$ matrices, this is a standard problem in computer science, and you just have to work it out using the specific dimensions of the given matrices.

Comment: @saulspatz Thank you for mentioning that